# Pine Script - How to add input with multiple options and match user selection?

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, pine-script-v5, pine-editor

I am trying to add an input with multiple options as shown below and to display a plot based on user selection in TradingView:

[image]

What I have tried is:

```
emaInput = input.string("50 EMA", "Choose EMA", options = ["50 EMA", "100 EMA", "200 EMA"])
upTrend = plot(dir == 1 and emaInput == '200 EMA' ? longStop : na, title='Uptrend Line', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
```

I'm getting the following error while saving the script:

> Cannot call 'operator and' with argument 'expr1'='emaInput'. An
> argument of 'input string' type was used but a 'series bool' is
> expected

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Provide the full code please, or at least a shortened version that is still a full script. I tried to replicate the issue with what you've sent, but it compiles fine for me, so perhaps the issue is in the lines you didn't include.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the input parameter to the below fixed the error:

```
emaInput = input.string(title='Choose EMA', options=["50 EMA", "100 EMA", "200 EMA"], defval="50 EMA")
```